# Integration Test Junit 5 and Spring boot Fails Due to Autowired Repository is Null

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa, junit5, java-17

I am facing an issue with my integration test when testing the interaction between my core library, which includes repositories and entities, and an H2 database. This test is crucial for validating the dynamic datasource functionality in a multi-tenant application. Here's the structure of my Maven project:

Project +parent-project +pom.xml +core-project (packaged as a JAR) +src +main +test +pom.xml +web-service-project (Contains the main class and has a dependency on the core-project) +pom.xml

Technical Stack:

JUnit 5

Spring Boot 3.0.3

Java 17

The error I encounter when running the test is as follows:

"Failed tests: net.wl.core.shared.dynamicdatasource.DataSourceRoutingIntegrationTest.test_should_switch_db(): Cannot invoke "net.wl.core.business.message.repository.MessageRepository.findAll()" because "this.messageRepository" is null."

It appears that the tests are running outside the Spring context.

```
Below are the essential files for analysis, and I am available to provide more information if needed:

**test class**

        package net.wl.core.shared.dynamicdatasource;
    
    
        import net.wl.core.shared.ClientDatabaseContextHolder;
        import net.wl.core.CoreApp;
        import net.wl.core.MockCoreConfiguration;
        import net.wl.core.business.message.entity.Messages;
        import net.wl.core.business.message.repository.MessageRepository;
        import net.wl.utilities.Constants;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
        import org.slf4j.Logger;
        import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
        import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
        import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
        import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
        import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
        import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
        import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext.ClassMode;
        import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
        import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
    
        import javax.sql.DataSource;
        import java.util.List;
    
        import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
        import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
    
        /**
         * Test Class for DataSourceRoutingIntegration
         *
         * @version 1.0.0
         * @since 1.0.0
         *
         */
        @Import(MockCoreConfiguration.class)
        @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/application-ut.properties" })
        @ActiveProfiles("ut")
        @SpringBootTest(classes = CoreApp.class)
        @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
        public class  DataSourceRoutingIntegrationTest {
    
        /**
         * The logger
         */
        private static final Logger LOGGER =           LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataSourceRoutingIntegrationTest.class);
    
        @Autowired
        DataSource routingDatasource;
    
        /**
         * List of the client datasources
         */
        @Value("${datasources}")
        private String datasources;
    
        /**
         * Spring injection of the service
         */
        @Autowired
        private MessageRepository messageRepository;
    
        /**
         *
         * Methode setup :
         *
         */
        @BeforeEach
        public void setup() {
    
            String[] datasourcesList = datasources.split(Constants.CHAR_SLASH);
    
            // init de la bdd H2
            for (String clientDatabase : datasourcesList) {
    
                ClientDatabaseContextHolder.set(clientDatabase);
                String scriptName = "websuitefee_" + clientDatabase + "_init_h2.sql";
                LOGGER.info("Execution du script SQL {} dans la BDD {}", scriptName, clientDatabase);
    
                Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(scriptName);
                ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(resource);
                databasePopulator.execute(routingDatasource);
                LOGGER.info("Chargement des donnees dans la BDD {} fait", clientDatabase);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         *
         * Methode shouldReturnSaveTransactionList :
         *
         */
        @Test
        public void test_should_switch_db() {
            ClientDatabaseContextHolder.set("LCL");
            List<Messages> transactionList = messageRepository.findAll();
            LOGGER.info("La taille de la liste de SaveSearchHead dans la BDD {} est de {}", "GCEP", transactionList.size());
            assertNotNull(transactionList);
            assertEquals(0, transactionList.size());
            ClientDatabaseContextHolder.clear();
        }
    }

**Data source configuration into src/test**

package net.core.shared.dynamicdatasource;

import net.wl.core.shared.ClientDataSourceRouter;
import net.wl.utilities.Constants;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

/**
 * Test Class for DataSourceRoutingTestConfiguration
 *
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 */
 @Configuration
 public class DataSourceRoutingTestConfiguration {

/**
 * List of the client datasources
 */
@Value("${datasources}")
public String datasources;

/**
 * Test pour une BDD chargee en memoire utilise la connection par defaut definie dans le fichier application-ut.properties
 * <p>
 * Methode clientEmbededDatasource :
 *
 * @return un ensemble de datasources
 */
@Bean
public DataSource clientEmbededDatasource() {
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();

    ClientDataSourceRouter clientRoutingDatasource = new ClientDataSourceRouter();

    String[] datasourcesList = datasources.split(Constants.CHAR_SLASH);

    // Parcourt de tous les clients déclarés dans ClientDatabase pour ouvrir une connection BDD correspondant à chacun
    for (String clientDatasource : datasourcesList) {
        DataSource datasource = customEmbededDatasource(clientDatasource);
        targetDataSources.put(clientDatasource, datasource);
        if ("BNP".equals(clientDatasource)) {
            clientRoutingDatasource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(datasource);
        }
    }

    clientRoutingDatasource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    return clientRoutingDatasource;
}

/**
 *
 * Methode customEmbededDatasource :
 *
 * @param schema le nom du client
 * @return le datasource associé au client
 */
private DataSource customEmbededDatasource(String schema) {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder dbBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();

    String schemaName = "websuitefee" + "_" + schema;

    System.out.println("Creation du schema : " + schemaName);
    return dbBuilder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).setName(schemaName).addScript("classpath:websuitefee_" + schema + "_init_h2.sql")
            .build();
}

/**
 * Test pour une BDD reelle sous docker ou sur un server, utilise les properties definies dans le fichier application-ut.properties 
 *
 * Methode clientDatasource :
 *
 * @return un ensemble de datasources
 */
public DataSource clientDatasource() {
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();

    ClientDataSourceRouter clientRoutingDatasource = new ClientDataSourceRouter();

    String[] datasourcesList = datasources.split(Constants.CHAR_SLASH);

    // Parcourt de tous les clients déclarés dans ClientDatabase pour ouvrir une connection BDD correspondant à chacun
    for (String clientDatasource : datasourcesList) {
        DataSource datasource = customDatasource(clientDatasource);
        targetDataSources.put(clientDatasource, datasource);
        if ("BNP".equals(clientDatasource)) {
            clientRoutingDatasource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(datasource);
        }
    }

    clientRoutingDatasource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    return clientRoutingDatasource;
}

/**
 *
 * Methode customDatasource :
 *
 * @param schema
 *            le nom du client
 * @return le datasource associé au client
 */
public DataSource customDatasource(String schema) {
    ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application-ut", Locale.FRANCE);

    String propertieBase = "spring.datasource." + schema + ".";

    DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(resource.getString(propertieBase + "driverClassName"));
    dataSourceBuilder.url(resource.getString(propertieBase + "url"));
    dataSourceBuilder.username(resource.getString(propertieBase + "username"));
    dataSourceBuilder.password(resource.getString(propertieBase + "password"));
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();

}
}

**main class into src/test**

package net.wl.core;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CoreApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CoreApp.class,args);
}
}

**core configuration into src/test**

package net.wl.core;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * Mock Core Configration for test
 *
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "net.wl.acquiring.websuite.uw67.core.business"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("net.wl.acquiring.websuite.uw67.core.business")
@EntityScan({ "net.wl.acquiring.websuite.uw67.core.business"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MockCoreConfiguration {

}

**application-ut.properties into src/test/ressources**

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
ASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS pojo
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS pojo
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.default_schema=pojo
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-  strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.release_mode=AFTER_STATEMENT
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true
logging.level.org.apache.http=DEBUG
uw5.i18n.message.source.cache.minutes=30
project.version=1.0
useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Paris
default.datasource=cl1
datasources=cl1/cl2/cl3/cl4/cl5
spring.datasource.cl1.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.cl1.initialize=false
spring.datasource.cl1.url=jdbc:h2:mem:websuitefee_cl1
spring.datasource.cl1.username=root
spring.datasource.cl1.password=root
spring.datasource.cl2.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.cl2.initialize=false 
spring.datasource.cl2.url=jdbc:h2:mem:websuitefee_cl2
spring.datasource.cl2.username=root
spring.datasource.cl2.password=root
spring.datasource.cl3.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.cl3.initialize=false
spring.datasource.cl3.url=jdbc:h2:mem:websuitefee_cl3
spring.datasource.cl3.username=root
spring.datasource.cl3.password=root
spring.datasource.cl4.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.cl4.initialize=false
spring.datasource.cl4.url=jdbc:h2:mem:websuitefee_cl4
spring.datasource.cl4.username=root
spring.datasource.cl4.password=root
spring.datasource.cl5.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.LBP.initialize=false
spring.datasource.cl5.url=jdbc:h2:mem:websuitefee_cl5
spring.datasource.cl5.username=root
spring.datasource.cl5.password=root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.type=trace
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false

**Example H2 script**

    CREATE TABLE `Messages` (
     `messageId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `cypheringKeyId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
     `message` text,
     `messageCode` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
     `messageDate` datetime NOT NULL,
     `messageProtocol` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
     `messageType` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
     `transactionId` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `dataOrigin` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `MESSAGE_INSERT_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `isInsertValidated` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`messageId`,`messageDate`),
     KEY `TransactionId` (`transactionId`) USING BTREE,
     KEY `Epuration` (`MESSAGE_INSERT_DATE`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=136547631 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `Messages` VALUES (146993,'BNP','message1','0100','2020-12-29      00:14:18','NLV','QUES/RESP',NULL,NULL,'2020-12-29 00:29:16',_binary ''),
    (146994,'BNP','message2','0100','2020-12-29 00:14:33','NLV','QUES/RESP',NULL,NULL,'2020-12-  29 00:29:16',_binary ''),
    (146995,'BNP','message3','0100','2020-12-29 00:19:33','NLV','QUES/RESP',NULL,NULL,'2020-12-29 00:29:16',_binary ''),
    (146996,'BNP','message4','0100','2020-12-29 00:31:56','NLV','QUES/RESP',NULL,NULL,'2020-12-29 00:43:39',_binary ''),
    (146997,'BNP','message5','0100','2020-12-29 00:27:21','NLV','QUES/RESP',NULL,NULL,'2020-12-29 00:43:39',_binary ''), 
    (146998,'BNP','message6','0100','2020-12-29 01:41:11','NLV','QUES/RESP',NULL,NULL,'2020-12-29 01:58:35',_binary '');

I expect that repositories will be autowired correctly, and the test will pass successfully
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.